# Blackberry audioplayer to pause?

Tags: blackberry

Hai i am creating audioPlayer to record Voice in my Blackberry application.I am using play()
and stop() to play and stop the player.can any one explain me how to use pause state in Blackberry Player?

Answer (score 0):

This question didn't indicate whether the OP was using the Java or WebWorks platform, however in the WebWorks platform you can use the `.pause()` method:

```
var playerInstance = new  blackberry.audio.Player("local:///mp3/track_01.mp3");
playerInstance.play();
/*
  do stuff...
*/
playerInstance.pause();
```

Docs: https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.audio.Player.html#.pause

If for the Java platform, if I recall correctly the `.stop()` method actually does perform a *pause* action.

Quote from the API docs:

```
public void stop()
      throws MediaException

      Stops the Player. It will pause the playback at the current media time.
```

Docs: http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/media/Player.html#stop%28%29